# How to insert more than 10,000 images in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have inserted over 10,000 images into my Google Sheet (mostly Rubik's cube algorithms and their cube diagram). They are 40-45KB PNG image, and I use the operation, `Insert -> Image -> Image in cell` to insert the image.

Suddenly after 2 years, and filling in over 10k images in one column I get this error message,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be an error occurred on the Google side. Submit your feedback directly to Google. To do this on the Google Sheets menus click on **Help** then **Help Sheets improve**